# Удаление ключа из словаря

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть словарь `{u'KI': [3, 5], u'Useobj': [1, 3, 4, 5], u'Status_law': [2, 3, 5], u'Present': []}`
Пытаюсь удалить из него ключи которых нет в эксель таблице

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  fc = r'R:\TEST\Test.xlsx'  
  f = r'R:\TEST\list.xlsx' #список ключей
  df = pd.read_excel(f) #чтение эксель со списком ключей
  df_1 = pd.read_excel(fc) 
  df_1 = df_1.set_index('ID') #замена индекса
  b = {i: df_1[df_1[i].isnull()].index.tolist() for i in df_1.columns} #создание словаря из экселя
  for d_1 in b:
      for d in df["Name"].unique():
          if d_1 != d:
              del b[d_1]
```

При попытке удалить появляется ошибка `KeyError: u'KI'`. Не могу понять почему она возникает и как её исправить.

Comment: она возникает, потому что на момент выполнения строки, которая указана в ошибке, в словаре нет ключа u'KI'

Comment: алгоритм удаления мало того, что неправильный, так еще и вредный - он удалит абсолютно всё (кроме, может быть, самого последнего оставшегося ключа в некоторых условиях)

Comment: Делайте лучше через операции над множествами, тут всё надо менять.

Comment: @Эникейщик если вот такой вариант ``b = {key: val for key, val in k.items() if key in df["Name"].unique()}`` ?